# Recordset does not return all data VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I am having some problem trying to extract some data from a recordset, the vba code is something as simple as this :

```
cnt.Open stDB

Query = "SELECT TriggerDescription,"
Query = Query & " FROM Research_Control"
Query = Query & " WHERE (((Research_Control.Status) = 1))"
Query = Query & " ORDER BY Research_Control.Enterprise;"

rs.Open Query, cnt, adUseClient

    While Not rs.EOF

        Sheets("Research_Review").Cells(lineResearch + line, colResearch) = rs.Fields(0)

        line = line + 1
        rs.MoveNext

    Wend

rs.Close

cnt.Close
```

The "TriggerDescription" is as large as 500 characteres and when I copy this value to a cell in excel it only appears until 300 characteres

So my question is : How can I extract all data from a recordset ?

PS: I have already tried changing the timeout with " cnt.CommandTimeout = 60 " but it does not work either

EDIT : In the Table Design the field "TriggerDescription" is a ntext DataType FYI.

Comment: Why all this **text...**?

Comment: That trigger description is not larger then 32,767 characters, as that is the max for a [cell](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)?

Comment: Depending on how large that text is and if the ADO DB provider for access supports it, you can try [`GetChunk`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681747(v=vs.85).aspx) on that field.

Comment: Does it exhibit the same if you use `Range.CopyFromRecodset`? You should prefer that anyway because it is easier than looping on the rs  and incrementing row number etc.

Comment: @Sami Sorry it was a way to exemplify how large it was the text inside the cell

Comment: @rene No, it is not actually it is around 500 characters. I will try the GetChunk and report here. Thanks for your help

Comment: @A.S.H Thanks for your help !! It worked with CopyFromRecordset however I am curious why this solution worked, do you have an answer for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@A.S.H has given the answer, using CopyFromRecordset I can copy all data to the cell

`Sheets("Test").Range("test").CopyFromRecordset rs`

Comment: Good to know it worked. Well, Excel's built-in methods are always preferable to custom loops, because they are optimized and robust. Why didn't it work with your loop is an enigma, but most likely because of a  certain limit on size for the assignment operator of Excel Cells.

Comment: @A.S.H Thanks ! I'll try to use more excel's built-in methods from now on